# How to stop Firefox from adapting to the theme used by Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, colors, themes

By default, Firefox includes three themes:

- Light, which is all white,
- Dark, which is all black, and
- Default, which is a combination of blue and white

At some point Mozilla added a [functionality](https://news.softpedia.com/news/mozilla-firefox-will-automatically-adapt-to-windows-10-dark-and-light-themes-521947.shtml) which allows Firefox's *default* theme to adapt to whichever theme Windows 10 is using. For example, if I am using the dark theme for Windows, then Firefox's default theme changes to dark. So if I choose the *default* Firefox theme and my Windows theme is dark, then Firefox switches to its Dark theme. If I choose the *default* Firefox theme and my Windows theme is light, then Firefox switches to its Light theme.

However, I prefer the blue-white theme. How do I disable this "feature"?

I am using Firefox 65.0.1.

Comment: @Biswapriyo I will be able to provide screenshots later today but for now I added some clarifications. This behavior should be reproducible on all Windows 10 machines. I know it happens to both my Windows 10 machines and I've tested it with a friend's machine as well.

Comment: Looking at the commit https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/48bb14249b06 it doesn't appear there is an about:config flag to disable this behaviour. You could always file a bug here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks, I arrived at the same conclusion but I was hoping for a nice hack to overcome this, thus why I posted it.

Comment: What happens if you disable the Dark theme from about:addons?

Comment: @spikey_richie Disabling the Dark theme makes Firefox switch to the Default theme which looks identical to the Dark theme (black). If I switch **Windows** to use the Light theme then Firefox's Default theme looks like its Light theme (white).

Answer (score 0):

A secret switch to disable dark theme integration exists in `about:config`
(found in the post
[disabling dark theme integration](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1238727)
):

Right-click on a blank space and create a new integer preference named `ui.systemUsesDarkTheme` and set it to `0` (zero) and restart Firefox.

Another post
[Disable themes](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1241145)
uses
[Customizing Firefox Using AutoConfig](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/customizing-firefox-using-autoconfig),
using the following lines:

```
lockPref("lightweightThemes.usedThemes","[]");
lockPref("lightweightThemes.selectedThemeID", "default-theme@mozilla.org");
```

You may try it with your theme id.